# Mixing ASP.NET Webforms with Friendly URLs with new ASP.NET MVC stuff

Tags: webforms, asp.net-mvc-5, friendly-url, asp.net-4.5

I have a number of "old-style" ASP.NET 4.x Webforms applications. For future development, we're thinking about switching to ASP.NET MVC 5, and we plan to basically add new features as MVC code to our existing apps.

Now I found a number of interesting articles on how to mix Webforms and ASP.NET MVC, and one of the topics usually is around routing. Typically, the consensus is to define a "route ignore" setting for all *.aspx requests - those get handled by the "old" Webforms runtime.

This is all nice and fine - but we're already using the Webforms "friendly URL" feature - so our requests are like

```
 http://myserver.com/myapp/customer/42
 http://myserver.com/myapp/product/edit/57
```

and we don't have any ".aspx" in our query string anymore.

So given this setup - Webforms 4.5.x with Friendly URL's (without the ".aspx" indicator) - how do I make sure that my new MVC routes don't collide with existing Webforms friendly URLs ?

Do I need to stick all the MVC stuff into an "area" (or several) and just define *those* URLs as the MVC routes? E.g.

```
http://myserver.com/myapp/mvc/newhotness/404
                          ***
```

or are there other, more compelling approaches to this?